# Insert text at specific index with a specific color in a RichTextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I want to insert a string in my `RichTextbox`, at a specific position and with a specific color. So I tried to add an extension for the method `AppendText()` of the `RichTextbox` class.

```
public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox Box, string Text, Color col, int SelectionStart)
{
    Box.SelectionStart = SelectionStart;
    Box.SelectionLength = 0;

    Box.SelectionColor = col;
    Box.SelectionBackColor = col;
    Box.Text = Box.Text.Insert(SelectionStart, Text);
    Box.SelectionColor = Box.ForeColor;
}
```

I tried to use this in a class called `RichTextBoxExtension`. The result is not as per my expectation. The string is inserted but not with the color selected.
Is there any better way to do this functionality?

EDIT: I think it could be interesting to inform you why I need this functionality. Actually, when user write a closing parenthesis, I would like to highligh (or color) the associative opening parenthesis.
so for example if the user write (Mytext), the first parenthesis will be in color when user tapped ")" and keep the selection on this parenthesis.

Comment: Setting the Text property will cause all formatting to be lost.  You must assign the SelectionText property instead.  Restoring the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties is required.  You'll discover the bug in the color selection by yourself.

Comment: I know it's a WinForms question, but if anyone stumbles here from the WPF-o-sphere, you can get access to the RichTextBox's underlying `FlowDocument` pretty easily using the `Document` property. -- This has a much more powerful editing API (and should be preferred over the WinForms editor, for other advanced features like spellchecking, etc.). -- If you're trapped in WinForms, it might be worth considering hosting the WPF Rich Text editor in an `ElementHost` control.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`SelectedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the RichTextBox control. Also make sure to keep track of the values of the current selection before you change anything.

Your code should look like this (I give away what Hans was hinting at) :

```
public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox Box, 
                              string Text,    
                              Color col, 
                              int SelectionStart)
{
    // keep all values that will change
    var oldStart = Box.SelectionStart;
    var oldLen = Box.SelectionLength;

    // 
    Box.SelectionStart = SelectionStart;
    Box.SelectionLength = 0;

    Box.SelectionColor = col;
    // Or do you want to "hide" the text? White on White?
    // Box.SelectionBackColor = col; 

    // set the selection to the text to be inserted
    Box.SelectedText = Text;

    // restore the values
    // make sure to correct the start if the text
    // is inserted before the oldStart
    Box.SelectionStart = oldStart < SelectionStart ? oldStart : oldStart + Text.Length; 
    // overlap?
    var oldEnd = oldStart + oldLen;
    var selEnd = SelectionStart + Text.Length;
    Box.SelectionLength = (oldStart < SelectionStart && oldEnd > selEnd) ? oldLen + Text.Length :  oldLen;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help! I will try this solution and will give you a feedback as soon as possible. Just to be sure I understand: The property selectedText is, actually, the text that I want to modify the color? Also, I the cursor will stay on this text selected no? In fact, for example if I wrote " (myvalue) " when I will write ")", the opening parenthesis "(" will be highlighted right? But if I continue to write something, is it possible to "remove" the "highlight action" ?  If my question is not clear, just tell me please. Sorry for mistakes, I know my english is not perfect ^^'